# AngularJS correctly display validation messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which should have validation messages displayed correctly, but at the moment the validation is allover the places.

- On submit I should be able to display the messages accordingly.
- On Submit I should have a response from my function to.
- Radio buttons arn't selectable

Please look at my demo and my json.
[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Srj7fleeDpBX1XxspGNp?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="userFormMethod()" name="userForm" novalidate>
  <fieldset>
    <div ng-repeat="field in result.fields">
      <label for="{{field.type}}">{{field.label}}</label>

      <input ng-if="field.type != 'radio'"
             name="{{field.name}}"
             ng-required="{{field.required}}"
             value="{{options.value}}" 
             type="{{field.type}}" />

      <div ng-if="field.type == 'radio'">
        <div ng-repeat="option in field.options">

          <input type="{{field.type}}"
                 name="{{field.name}}"
                 ng-required="{{field.required}}"
                 ng-model="richestClub"
                 value="{{option.value}}" />{{option.label}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <form-error ng-show="{{!!field.errorMessages.required}}">{{field.errorMessages.required}}</form-error>
      <form-error ng-show="{{!!field.errorMessages.invalid}}">{{field.errorMessages.invalid}}</form-error>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

 <button type="submit"
         ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"
         ng-click="onSubmit(userForm)"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var myApp=angular.module('CreateApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
    console.log($scope.fields);
  });


$scope.userForm = function (user) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mytestserver.com/that/does/not/exists',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        transformRequest: function (data) {
            var postData = [];
            for (var prop in data)
            postData.push(encodeURIComponent(prop) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[prop]));
            return postData.join("&");
        },
        data: user
    });
}


  $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
    var fields = response.fields;
    $scope.richestClub = fields.answer.options[0].value;
    console.log($scope.richestClub);
    console.log($scope.fields);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll list a few things that can be quickly fixed with the form then point you in a more Angular direction for validation:

- You need the name attribute in your JSON e.g. `"name": "Email"`. This is why your radio buttons are allowing multiple selected, because radio buttons are grouped by name. Also Angular's way of validation uses the name property to identify each field, which you can see in the linked tutorial.
- The `ng-click` function for the form submit isn't needed, by using `ng-form` and having the button type `submit` then the function assigned to `ng-form` will be run when the button is pressed.
- For any angular validation to work each input will need a `ng-model`
- With the validation itself you are trying to mix HTML5 validation with Angular, which can work, but isn't the best way to do it. For a look at the  Angular way to validate forms check [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation), that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

I have made a few edits to the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1KwWH6k6aYKQIJrPT6GL?p=preview), but it still doesn't have working validation, but hopefully the info I have given you can put you in right direction.

Comment: thanks, I'm having problem to validate it because I have the json file and the messages on it to which complicates things out, are you able to help?

Comment: please check this modified Demo, http://plnkr.co/edit/Srj7fleeDpBX1XxspGNp?p=preview the ng-click was quite important in order to send the post request. "userForm"

Comment: You haven't change the name of the function assigned to `ng-form` that is why the post isn't happening.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tMGzI7DJF30FfnlW0sZj?p=preview like this see now it hits the post function

Comment: The fnPtr is because you're naming the method `userform` which is the name the form has already creating issues in scope because two things exist called `userform`

Comment: yep, got it, and the messages ? able to help please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133347/discussion-between-dd77-and-callum).

Comment: MY issue here is the json file, which controls it .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **ngMessages** .
[Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages) is a tutorial if you want to implement it into a form.

With ngMessage you don't have to put too much code to validate

[This tutorial](https://www.google.com.ar/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=ionic%20ngmessage%20form%20validation&oq=ionic%20ngmessage%20form%20validation&aqs=chrome..69i57.8095j0j4) is for ionic framework but works perfect with your code.

**Cheers!**

Comment: Would you be able to help to implement it? I tried already, I have the json file which complicates things for me.